# Karate 0.9.6 to 1.0.1 upgrade issue with array param

Tags: karate

When sending an empty array param in karate the param is not sent.

Example:

```
Given url homeUrl
And path 'types'
And param filterTypes = []
When method GET
Then status 200
And mach response = '#[0]'
```

Running karate in debug mode I see the following get request

**In version 0.9.6**

GET https://{homeUrl}/types?filterTypes=%5B%5D

**In version 1.0.1**

GET https://{homeUrl}/types?

Comment: Sure, it is updated now. Will it be a similar answer to this question?

Comment: ok, I have answered this one now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a string. These four lines below will work on 1.1.0, try it and see for yourself.

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/get'
* param foo = '[]'
* method get
* status 200
* match response.url == 'https://httpbin.org/get?foo=[]'
```

And here is the request in the log:

```
1 > GET https://httpbin.org/get?foo=%5B%5D
1 > Host: httpbin.org
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.11)
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```